# animate slide up and down UIView based on indexPath.row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, slidedown, slideup

right now I'm trying to move up and move down an UIView based on roll up or down in UITableView. So, if I rolled up the view, which means indexPath.row will keep incremented; the view will appear slide down until certain position and stopped. Then when I rolled down the table view, which means indexPath.row, decremented; the view will disappear by slide up outside the display view.

Do anyone have any idea what I need to code? Right now I'm just simply able to hide and unhide the view. I need the code for animate it slide up and down.

```
   mark=indexPath.row;
   flag=flag+1;
   if (flag-mark>1) {
      postBox.hidden=NO;
      flag=indexPath.row;
   }
   else
      postBox.hidden=YES;
```

Thanks in advance for your help ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move the view according to the movement of the UITableView, you can calculate the content offset of the UITableView and apply it to your moving view. Declare a ivar of type CGFloat named lastOffset.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat distance = scrollView.contentOffset.y - lastOffset;
    lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.movingView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.movingView.frame, 0.0f, distance);
    }];
}
```